# Looking for best approach for signature button on xpage

Tags: xpages

I need a simple button whereby a user clicks to sign off on a document.   A single signer per document, but when they click it, it puts their name and the date in two visible fields, and changes the status field.

What is the best approach for this?   This is probably drop-dead simple but for some reason I cannot get it working.

They have been forced to log in by this time.

Thanks in advance.

Matt

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code that we can comment on :-)

Comment: One way to solve this, would be to set the fields directly in the document (context/bean) and reload/refresh the page. So you would not have to deal with the editmode..

Comment: Sorry guys....yesterday was just not a good day.  This was in fact very simple and once I looked at it again, I got it working easily.   But thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
        <xp:this.data>
            <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="test"></xp:dominoDocument>
        </xp:this.data>
        <xp:panel id="panelMain">
            <xp:table>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td colspan="2">
                        <xp:label value="Main Form" id="label1"></xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td style="width:100.0px">
                        <xp:label value="Now" id="label2"></xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="${javascript:return @Now();}">
                            <xp:this.converter>
                                <xp:convertDateTime type="both"></xp:convertDateTime>
                            </xp:this.converter>
                        </xp:text>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
            </xp:table>
        </xp:panel>
        <xp:panel id="panelSignature" style="background-color:rgb(192,192,192)">
            <xp:button value="I Agree" id="button1">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="SignatureTable">
                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    document1.replaceItemValue("SignedDate",@Now());
    document1.replaceItemValue("SignedBy",userBean.getDisplayName());}]]></xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>
            <xp:table id="SignatureTable">
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td colspan="2">
                        <xp:label value="SignatureTable" id="label3"></xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td style="width:100.0px">
                        <xp:label value="SignedBy" id="label6"></xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:inputText id="computedField4" value="#{document1.SignedBy}" readonly="true"></xp:inputText>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td style="width:100.0px">
                        <xp:label value="SignedDate" id="label5"></xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:inputText id="computedField3" value="#{document1.SignedDate}" readonly="true">
                            <xp:this.converter>
                                <xp:convertDateTime type="both"></xp:convertDateTime>
                            </xp:this.converter>
                        </xp:inputText>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
            </xp:table>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:view>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Paul...learned something new today (userBean, did not know it existed).     I have it working perfectly.   I appreciate everyone's attempts to  help me as I get more acclimated with all this.

Comment: You're welcome ... btw, for this and future its best to check the answer that solved your problem ... helps other readers and the poster gets points ;)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by this "They have been forced to log in by this time." your problem is in your ACL. Seems, you allow anonymous reading of the document, but in the moment you want to save it, ACL does not allow anonymous users to do that, so Domino asks for their identity.

Set anonymous access to No access level.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a button, but if the user is not logged in and does not have anonymous edit access, then a login dialog will appear.  For a signing function, I assume the user must be logged in to sign.  `document1` is the Xpage data document to be signed.

```
    <xp:button
        value="Sign"
        id="button1"
        styleClass="btn btn-primary">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
                <xp:this.action>
                    <xp:executeScript>
                        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                        document1.appendItemValue("SignerName", session.getEffectiveUsername();
                        document1.document1("SignedDate",       session.createDateTime(@Now()));
                        document1.save();                                       
                    }]]></xp:this.script>
                </xp:executeScript>
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
```

If you need to update a document without logging in, then in the button, you will have to get the doc with `sessionAsSigner` and then update.